# R/rgl - How to move 3d axis labels?

Tags: r, 3d, axis-labels, rgl

(I am using rgl.)  I am would like to move the axis labels in the following:

```
plot3d(1,2,3, xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="z", xlim=c(-4,4), ylim=c(-4,4), zlim=c(-4,4))
abclines3d(x = matrix(0, ncol=3), a = diag(3), col="black", lwd=3)
```

To the positions shown:

[image: Red arrows showing that I want the labels next to the positive x,y,and z axes]

Basically, I'd like the labels to be at the "ends" of the positive x, y, and z axes.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
plot3d(1,2,3, xlab="", ylab="", zlab="", xlim=c(-4,4), ylim=c(-4,4), zlim=c(-4,4))
abclines3d(x = matrix(0, ncol=3), a = diag(3), col="black", lwd=3)
text3d(matrix(c(3,0.2,0.2,4,-6,4,0.1,0.1,3),ncol=3),texts=c('y', 'x', 'z'))
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that's close!  Except that as I rotate, the "y" and "z" are not quite at the ends of their respective axes.  Can you tweak that positioning a little?

Comment: @anon I think the best option will be to try different values of the text location that suits your exact requirement.

Comment: You mean I have to figure it out for myself? =)

Comment: Yeah basically you need to play with some numeric values for the text positions in the text3d function.